# UITextView Formating purpose by adding line in ios sdk

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I want to add line in my UITextView in which there is a line under text written in the UITextview for formatting purpose.

How to do it ? there is any other way instead of adding background image ?

> I want text between two line not underline text.

[image]

Comment: Make the text attributed string and add line to its attributes.

Comment: not getting .. can you answer ?

Comment: Maulik has already answered it. There is no default way of doing what you want to do AFAIK

Comment: see my another answer @Florence

Comment: @Maulik before your answer I got my solution in answer of #Riddhi Patel ... Thanks for your help... I had tried your code.. but its not working with iOS 9.. its till iOS 6...

Comment: see i add two answer for your question...another answer working for me

Comment: I had seen that you had anwered two time... but I got my solution in Riddhi's answer before you had answered...

Answer (score 3):

Try to use NSAttributedString as follows and set in UITextView.

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Some String"];
[attString addAttribute:(NSString*)kCTUnderlineStyleAttributeName 
                   value:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kCTUnderlineStyleSingle] 
                   range:(NSRange){0,[attString length]}];
```

For more info on NSAttributedString check this How do you use NSAttributedString?

For eg:-

```
textView.attributedText = attString;
```

[From apple documentation on UITextView,](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/index.html)

```
@property(nonatomic,copy) NSAttributedString *attributedText
```

**Discussion:** This property is nil by default. Assigning a new value to this property also replaces the value of the text property with the same string data, albeit without any formatting information. In addition, assigning a new a value updates the values in the font, textColor, and textAlignment properties so that they reflect the style information starting at location 0 in the attributed string.

Comment: I dont want underline.. I want different output.. See my edit

Answer (score 2):

You can use attribute string,for example

```
NSDictionary * attribtues = @{NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName:@(NSUnderlineStyleSingle),
                              NSUnderlineColorAttributeName:[UIColor blueColor]};
NSAttributedString * attributeStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"This has a under line" attributes:attribtues];
self.textview.attributedText  = attributeStr;
```

If you want the default input text have a under line

```
NSDictionary * attribtues = @{NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName:@(NSUnderlineStyleSingle),
                              NSUnderlineColorAttributeName:[UIColor blueColor]};
self.textview.typingAttributes = attribtues;
```

Gif

[image]

Comment: I dont want underline.. I want different output.. See my edit

Answer (score 1):

Very simple third party library is available to [NoteView is a sub class of UITextView to show lines for each row in text view.](https://github.com/aahsanali/NoteView)

Add NoteView.h & NoteView.m files into your project. Create its instance or IBOutlet like you create for UITextView.

Implement UITextViewDelegete method:

Other library is [MPTextView](http://%20github.com/cbowns/MPTextView) which also support placeholder.

Answer (score 1):

You should try and draw your lines programmatically rather than using an image. Here's some sample code of how you could accomplish that. You can subclass UITextView and override it's drawRect: method.

**mynotes.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface mynotes : UITextView <UITextViewDelegate> {
}
@end
```

**mynotes.m**

```
    #import "mynotes.h"

    @implementation mynotes

    - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

        self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
        if (self) {
            self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:0.6f alpha:1.0f];
            self.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"MarkerFelt-Thin" size:19];
        }
        return self;
    }

    - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

        //Get the current drawing context   
        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(); 
        //Set the line color and width
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f green:0.0f blue:0.0f alpha:0.2f].CGColor);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0f);
        //Start a new Path
        CGContextBeginPath(context);

        //Find the number of lines in our textView + add a bit more height to draw lines in the empty part of the view
        NSUInteger numberOfLines = (self.contentSize.height + self.bounds.size.height) / self.font.leading;

        //Set the line offset from the baseline. (I'm sure there's a concrete way to calculate this.)
        CGFloat baselineOffset = 6.0f;

        //iterate over numberOfLines and draw each line
        for (int x = 0; x < numberOfLines; x++) {
            //0.5f offset lines up line with pixel boundary
            CGContextMoveToPoint(context, self.bounds.origin.x, self.font.leading*x + 0.5f + baselineOffset);
            CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.bounds.size.width, self.font.leading*x + 0.5f + baselineOffset);
        }

        //Close our Path and Stroke (draw) it
        CGContextClosePath(context);
        CGContextStrokePath(context);
    }

@end
```

**MyViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "mynotes.h"
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate> {

    mynotes *note;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) mynotes *note;

@end
```

**MyViewController.m**

```
#import "MyViewController.h"
#import "mynotes.h"

#define KEYBOARD_HEIGHT 216

@implementation MyViewController
@synthesize note;

- (void)loadView {
    [super loadView];
    self.note = [[[NoteView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds] autorelease];
    [self.view addSubview:note];
    note.delegate = self;
    note.text = @"This is the first line.\nThis is the second line.\nThis is the ... line.\nThis is the ... line.\nThis is the ... line.\nThis is the ... line.\nThis is the ... line.\n";
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    [note setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
    CGRect frame = self.view.bounds;
    frame.size.height -= KEYBOARD_HEIGHT;
    note.frame = frame;
}

- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
    note.frame = self.view.bounds;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [note release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Take a look at Apple's documentation for [Managing the Keyboard](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html), specifically "Moving Content That Is Located Under the Keyboard". It explains how to listen for NSNotifcations and adjust your views properly.

**Output like this**

[image]